# Android: Need to save checkbox state in a custom adapter listview

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I need to be able to save the state of the checkboxes. When the app the closes, it should save which checkboxes were checked and when the app comes back on, the checkboxes that were checked should be checked at startup. It uses a custom adapter listview. Thank You for your time.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Generate list View from ArrayList
    displayListView();

}



private void displayListView() {

    //Array list of countries
    ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    Country country = new Country("","Challenge 1",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("ALB","Albania",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("DZA","Algeria",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("ASM","American Samoa",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("AND","Andorra",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("AGO","Angola",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("AIA","Anguilla",false);
    countryList.add(country);

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.country_info, countryList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Clicked on Row: " + country.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                    Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                    " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Country country = countryList.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(country);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

}

**Country.Java**

```
public class Country {

String code = null;
String name = null;
boolean selected = false;

public Country(String code, String name, boolean selected) {
    super();
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/some_text" android:textSize="20sp" />


<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**country_info.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

**Edit**

I put the load preferences in the getView() method but one problem is that "this" in the parameter of sharedPreferences is underlined. Also I put the savePreferences() method and onPause() method at the end of the code but holder.name seems not to work out there.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Generate list View from ArrayList
    displayListView();

}







private void displayListView() {

    //Array list of countries
    ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    Country country = new Country("","Challenge 1",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("ALB","Albania",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("DZA","Algeria",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("ASM","American Samoa",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("AND","Andorra",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("AGO","Angola",false);
    countryList.add(country);
    country = new Country("AIA","Anguilla",false);
    countryList.add(country);

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.country_info, countryList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Clicked on Row: " + country.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);



            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
            if (checkBoxValue) {
                holder.name.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.name.setChecked(false);
            }




            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                    Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                    " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Country country = countryList.get(position);
        holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(country);

        return convertView;

    }

}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", holder.name.isChecked());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Android Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save the checkboxes state:

EDIT:

To make a separation of concerns you should keep the persistency logic in the models:

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

```
public class Country {

private static final String PREFERENCES_NAMESPACE = "checkboxes_states";

String code = null;
String name = null;
boolean selected = false;
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

public Country(Context context, String code, String name, boolean selected) {
    super();
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    mSettings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAMESPACE, 0);
    mEditor = mSettings.edit();
    setSelected(mSettings.getBoolean(code, selected));
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    if(this.selected != selected) { // update if changed
        mEditor.putBoolean(getCode(), selected);
        mEditor.commit();
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
}
```

Don't forget to pass the app context when initialising a Country object.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but isn't that just for regular listview checkboxes and not for custom adapters, and if it can be used in my case, where should i put this code?

Comment: In the getView method when you are loading the custom adapter view, instantiate the check box, and put an event listener to save the state upon changes

Comment: I still can not implement it, can you please write a sample code for this portion were i'm supposed to implement it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SoheilAtashpanjeh can you edit the question with the changes that you made with SharedPreferences ?

Comment: view my changes @SoheilAtashpanjeh

Comment: @SoheilAtashpanjeh any luck? is your problem solved?

Comment: Thank for your help but how do I "pass the app context when initialising a Country object"

Comment: countryList.add(country);
country = new Country(this, "ALB","Albania",false);